# Error: Permission denied @ dir_chdir - /root

Tags: linux

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему когда я нахожусь в директории `/root`и ввожу команду `$ brew install redis`, я получаю

```
Error: Permission denied @ dir_chdir - /root
```

Как это обойти?
 Гугление не помогло :(

Comment: побуду переводчиком: «permission denied» == «нет доступа». и подсказчиком: запускайте команду в **вашем** домашнем каталоге.

Comment: Ну, или запускайте программу от имени root,

Answer (score 0):

Was getting

erma4inapower@MacBook-Pro-Dmitrij  ~  brew services start php
Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/erma4inapower/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist

Ended up:

sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/erma4inapower/Library/LaunchAgents/

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык